# Merge [google-truth] and [truth]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I suggest merging [google-truth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-truth) and [truth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truth) as they refer to the same thing.

Description of [google-truth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-truth):

> Google Truth is a github-hosted assertion/proposition framework
>   appropriate for testing, inspired by FEST, and driven by some
>   extensibility needs, written nearly entirely by Google employees in
>   their spare time or contributing in their capacity as Java core
>   librarians. Truth can be used in place of JUnit's assertions, FEST,
>   AssertJ, or Hamcrest's matchers, or it can be used alongside where
>   other approaches seem more suitable.

Description of [truth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truth):

> Google Truth is a github-hosted assertion/proposition framework
>   appropriate for testing, inspired by FEST, and driven by some
>   extensibility needs, written nearly entirely by Google employees in
>   their spare time or contributing in their capacity as Java core
>   librarians. Truth can be used in place of JUnit's assertions, FEST,
>   AssertJ, or Hamcrest's matchers, or it can be used alongside where
>   other approaches seem more suitable.

Comment: Someone created `truth` two days ago end edited it into all questions that were tagged `google-truth`...

Comment: Am I the only one who finds the title of this question concerning, in a broad, philosophical sense?

Comment: @Marco13 That depends on your [tag:version] of truth.

Comment: Google Truth is the only Truth.

Comment: ewww. That should **not** be a tag either @heenenee

Comment: @Neal There's separate [tag:versions] of that tag too.

Comment: :-( oy... @heenenee

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just reversed what [Floern said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/559745/floern) and just removed that new tag from all of the questions it was just added to.

Now it is up to the automatic jobs to clean up the dead tag (or a mod).